# Maven gives a error when trying to execute the "mvn build" command

Tags: maven

When I run my maven project through "run as "==> "Maven build" in my eclipse IDE,the error what is shown in the under img happened.
![enter image description here][1]

My JDK version is:1.7.0_76
Maven version is:3.3.1
echo %JAVA_hOME%=D:\work\Java\jdk1.7.0_76
echo %M2_HOME%=D:\work\apache-maven-3.3.3
In my eclipse IDE My maven setting like the under img:![enter image description here][2]![enter image description here][3]

My project's build path is ![enter image description here][4]

This is because this project is an old project compiled with JDK1.6,so,I choose the installed jdk1.6. But when run as maven build,the error like picture 1 happened!

Help me ,pls!

```
The error is 【[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.084 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-07-11T01:15:18+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/154M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoGoalSpecifiedException
```

】

Answer (score 0):

If you select *Run As* → *Maven build* an Eclipse *Run Configuration* is used (see menu *Run* → *Run Configurations...*). In case of a *Maven Build* at least one appropriate goal (e.g. one of [Maven's built-in lifecycles](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference)) has to be specified in its *Goals:* field.